# Line color is override on first line color in android

Tags: android, fingerprinting

I am trying to draw line using finger paint and I want to draw that line in multi color all are working fine. But what happen is at the first time when I draw a line then it works fine but after that if I draw another line then the color of first line will lose from that and it will become like a single color line.

Any Reference link is also appreciate ..!!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I can only assume that the difference between colors depends of the `hue` property, which is created from the size of `pointsToDraw`.

```
// set paint to whatever color you want
float hue = (float)i /pointsToDraw.size();
```

Every line you draw on screen is not the exact copy of previous, right?, so the `pointsToDraw` will vary in size, and as a result the `hue` will have different values for different lines.

And since the `hue` is used in generation of the line color, every new line will have a unique color.

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.HSVToColor(
      new float[] {
           hue*360, 1, 1
      }));
```

To test this assumption, try to assign a constant value to `hue`, and see if any difference.

Comment: Instead of deviding to `pointsToDraw.size()`, try to devide to a constant value, like: `hue = (float)i /200;` Play with different values and see if any result.

Answer (score 1):

What your code is doing is simply smoothly changing the color when painting a new segment of each path.
This is done in lines :

```
float hue = (float)i /pointsToDraw.size();  
mPaint.setColor(Color.HSVToColor(
                                new float[] {
                                        hue*360, 1, 1
                                }));
```

`hue` is smoothly changing because i is your iteration variable.
The problem with your code is that instead of using some constant value as divisor to compute `hue` , you are using a value that was depending on the number of paths you had on your screen (i.e. `pointsToDraw.size()`).

So I think the following code will do it. (what I did is just changing the divisor to compute `hue`

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if(clearCanvas)
        {  // Choose the colour you want to clear with.
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            clearCanvas = false;
            fl.invalidate();
        }else {

            synchronized(pointsToDraw)
            {
                for (ArrayList<Point> paths : pointsToDraw) {

                    for (int i=0; i<paths.size()-1; ++i) {

                        // set paint to whatever color you want
                        float hue = (float)i /(paths.get(0).x+paths.get(0).y);  
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.HSVToColor(
                                new float[] {
                                        hue*360, 1, 1
                                }));
                        canvas.drawLine(paths.get(i).x, paths.get(i).y, paths.get(i+1).x, paths.get(i+1).y, mPaint);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```